# Machine learning-based edge detector

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning

I have Read the following [blog](https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2016/08/fast-and-accurate-document-detection-for-scanning/) on edge detection using machine learning. They

> used a modern machine learning-based algorithm. The algorithm is trained on images where humans annotate the most significant edges and object boundaries. Given this labeled dataset, a machine learning model is trained to predict the probability of each pixel in an image belonging to an object boundary.

I would like to implement this technique using opencv.

Does anybody have an idea or know how this method can be implemented/developped using Opencv ?

How can we annotate the most significant edges and object boundaries for use with machine learning algorith ?

Comment: I don't think the guys at drop box startet off with a question on stackoverflow. 
your question is too broad. you can impement anything in opencv, it just depends on how much code you're willing to add...

Comment: The guys has Provided Technical details about his solution and i am trying to implement it with opencv. The question seems to me very clear and precise.

Answer (score 3):

There are strong edge detection algorithms on opncv. The famous on is Hough transform (conjuction of lines which is described on the blog). Most of the strong edge detectors are based on gradient; gradient in x or y or both direction. I want to introduce you [Sobel edge detector](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html) and [Laplacian](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d0f/tutorial_py_gradients.html). both are provided in opencv.
For the case that you want problem is tricky and depends on your date set. There are many papers published for this important problem among those I provide you the following links:

1. [Dollar slides at U. Toronto](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/%7Efidler/slides/CSC420/lecture5.pdf)
2. [Review Paper from U. twente](https://ris.utwente.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/5344269)
3. [Github repository s9xie](https://github.com/s9xie/hed)

Comment: 3rd one is now integrated into OpenCV's dnn module. So, you can run deep learning based edge detection directly from opencv with a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Now you have to obtain a dataset with edges annotated in them, like dropbox did. This would then be your starting point. Then you can learn about neural networks in the documentation section of #deep-learning. So called U-shaped networks are the current state-of-the-art in segmentation like shown in (https://github.com/EdwardTyantov/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation). This can easily be adopted to be used for your task.

Still I would imagine that annotating thousands of images is not really what you were looking for. If you do not want to learn the edge detector you can use something more classical like canny or sobel (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection), as is stated in the blog post you provided.